# C# - Getting keyboard input after event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, input, keyboard

so I have an assignment for an HCI course, and I can figure everything out but one part. Here's the actual question:

> On your main form drop a panel and change its color. When the user enters “r” and then inputs 
>   a number, n, move the panel n pixels to the right. If the user enters “l” and then inputs a 
>   number, n, move the panel n pixels to the left.

What I'm struggling with is capturing the integer after the first keystroke. i.e., after "r" is pressed, how could I go about getting the input that follows? Here's my event handler so far:

```
        private void rightLeftForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "R")
        {
            //Move panel to the right

        }

        else if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "L")
        {
            //Move panel to the left
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where in this code are you checking for the `char.IsDigit Or char.IsNumber`? there are several ways to do this you could do a for loop and check each char..If you do not want to do a loop try something like this inside your if statement `if(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar){then you know it's a number that was entered }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to remember which key "L" or "R" was pressed by the user and store this information. Next time your key handler is called with a number key, you can then act depending on the state you've stored.

Example:

```
// enum to store panel movement direction
public enum PanelMovement
{
    None;
    Left;
    Right;
}

// member variable to store last panel movement
private PanelMovement mCurrentMovement = PanelMovement.None;

private void rightLeftForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "R")
        {
            // store direction after player has pressed "R"
            mPanelMovement = PanelMovement.Right;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "L")
        {
           // store direction after player pressed "L" 
           mPanelMovement = PanelMovement.Left;
        }
        // react on number key pressed
        else if(e.KeyCode >= Keys.D1 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)
        {
            if(mPanelMovement == PanelMovement.Left)
               // move panel left
            else if(mPanelMovement == PanelMovement.Right)
              // move panel right
        }
    }
```